# Spring Cloud Feign report 404

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign

I use `Eureka` to register a service and use `Feign` to discover services, but if I don't add URL parameters, the system will report 404 exceptions.
And my code id below that does not work :

```
@FeignClient(name = "CRAWLER-SERVICE")
```

And Below code works :

```
@FeignClient(name = "crawler-service", url = "http://192.168.199.229:8091/crawler")
```

**Stack trace :**

```
feign.FeignException: status 404 reading CrawlerServiceApi#queryAllConditions(String,String)
    at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:62) ~[feign-core-9.5.0.jar:na]
    at feign.codec.ErrorDecoder$Default.decode(ErrorDecoder.java:91) ~[feign-core-9.5.0.jar:na]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:138) ~[feign-core-9.5.0.jar:na]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:76) ~[feign-core-9.5.0.jar:na]
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:103) ~[feign-core-9.5.0.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy120.queryAllConditions(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.gezizhi.boss.controller.CrawlerConditionController.queryAllSource(CrawlerConditionController.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.gezizhi.boss.controller.CrawlerConditionController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$bd843b81.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
```

The **eureka configuration** is：

```
server:
  port: 8761
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
  server:
    enable-self-preservation: false
    wait-time-in-ms-when-sync-empty: 0
```

And the client configuration is：

```
eureka:
  instance:
    lease-expiration-duration-in-seconds: 2
    lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds: 1
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://127.0.0.1:8761/eureka/
```

**The server code:**

```
  @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/api/crawler")
    public class CrawlerConditonApi {
        private final CrawlerConditonService crawlerConditonService;

        @Autowired
        public CrawlerConditonApi(CrawlerConditonService crawlerConditonService) {
            this.crawlerConditonService = crawlerConditonService;
        }

        @GetMapping("/conditions")
        public String queryAllConditions(String belongDatasource, String conditionStatus) {
            return crawlerConditonService.queryAllCondition(belongDatasource, conditionStatus);
        }

        @PostMapping("/conditions")
        public String insertConditon(String params, String belongDatasource) {
            return crawlerConditonService.insertConditon(params, belongDatasource);
        }

        @PutMapping("/conditions/{id}/status/{status}")
        public String updateCondition(@PathVariable("id") String id, @PathVariable("status") String status) {
            return crawlerConditonService.updateCondition(id, status);
        }
    }
```

**THE CLIENT CODE:**

```
@FeignClient(name = "CRAWLER-SERVICE")
public interface CrawlerServiceApi {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/papersources/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    String queryAllSource();

    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/papersources/{id}/status/{status}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    String updateSource(@PathVariable("id") String id, @PathVariable("status") String status);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/crawler/conditions", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    String queryAllConditions(@RequestParam("belongDatasource") String belongDatasource,
                          @RequestParam("conditionStatus") String conditionStatus);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/crawler/conditions", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    String insertConditon(@RequestParam("params") String params,
                          @RequestParam("belongDatasource") String belongDatasource);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/crawler/conditions/{id}/status/{status}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    String updateCondition(@PathVariable("id") String id, @PathVariable("status") String status);
}
```

And I use in Controller:

```
@RestController
public class CrawlerConditionController {
    private final CrawlerServiceApi crawlerServiceApi;

    @Autowired
    public CrawlerConditionController(CrawlerServiceApi crawlerServiceApi) {
        this.crawlerServiceApi = crawlerServiceApi;
    }

    @GetMapping("/conditions/query")
    public AbstractResult queryAllSource(@RequestParam("belongDatasource") String belongDatasource,
                                         @RequestParam("conditionStatus") String conditionStatus) {
        return ApiInvokeRspUtil.returnDataRowsInvokeRsp("CRL00000",
                crawlerServiceApi.queryAllConditions(belongDatasource, conditionStatus));
    }

    @PostMapping("/conditions/add")
    public AbstractResult addConditon(@RequestParam("paramJson") String paramJson,
                                         @RequestParam("belongDataSource") String belongDataSource) {
        return ApiInvokeRspUtil.returnDataRowsInvokeRsp("CRL00000",
                crawlerServiceApi.insertConditon(paramJson, belongDataSource));
    }

    @PostMapping("/conditions/{id}/status/{status}")
    public AbstractResult updateConditon(@PathVariable("id") String id,
                                         @PathVariable("status") String status) {
        return ApiInvokeRspUtil.returnDataRowsInvokeRsp("CRL00000",
                crawlerServiceApi.updateCondition(id, status));
    }
}
```

**application.yml** which contain CrawlerConditonApi's project

```
server:
  context-path: /crawler
  port: 8091

eureka:
  instance:
    lease-expiration-duration-in-seconds: 2
    lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds: 1
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://127.0.0.1:8761/eureka/

spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gezizhi?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8
    username: root
    password: password
    initialSize: 5
    minIdle: 5
    maxActive: 20
    maxWait: 60000
    timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 60000
    minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 300000
    validationQuery: SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
    testWhileIdle: true
    testOnBorrow: false
    testOnReturn: false
    poolPreparedStatements: true
    maxPoolPreparedStatementPerConnectionSize: 20
    filters: stat,wall,log4j
    connectionProperties: druid.stat.mergeSql=true;druid.stat.slowSqlMillis=5000
  redis:
    database: 0
    host: 127.0.0.1
    port: 6379
    password: password
    pool:
      max-idle: 10
      max-wait: 10000
      max-active: 1024
      min-idle: 1
    timeout: 3000
  application:
    name: crawler-service

mybatis:
  type-aliases-package: com.gezizhi.crawler.dao.domain
  mapper-locations: classpath:mybatis/*.xml
```

Comment: How are you calling a resource url using FeignClient?

Comment: `@RequestMapping(value = "/api/crawler/conditions", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    String queryAllConditions(@RequestParam("belongDatasource") String belongDatasource,
                          @RequestParam("conditionStatus") String conditionStatus);`

Comment: I have already edited my question, plz look at the added code,thx!

Comment: is your `crawler-service` properly registered in Eureka Server? could you ckeck the logs?

Comment: @gWombat yes,I can show the service in eureka admin panel

Comment: @Mehraj Malik  None of them can work.

Comment: @Youngs never post sensitive information like `Password`, I've edit the question.

Comment: @Mehraj Malik Thank you, thispassword is my local db password,I won't use it in public network environment. Thank you again for your advice, and I will remember it.

Comment: Feign is not using eureka as you are using the `url` attribute of `@FeignClient`.

Comment: In your Eureka Server, make sure you add `@EnableEurekaServer`, and in your client make sure you add both: `@EnableEurekaClient` & `@EnableFeignClients`

Comment: @Youngs if you found solution, please remember to post it.

Comment: @AndersMetnik sorry, there is not a solution for now.

Comment: @Youngs just got mine to work, how does you application classes look ?

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, still posting my answer so it may help someone else as I had the same problem and finally was able to solve it.

It happened due to `server.context` which is set to `crawler`. Since this effectively adds a new url segment, you need to change your feign client to below (mind the context added after service name)

```
@FeignClient(name = "CRAWLER-SERVICE/crawler")
```

Or you need to change the `RequestMapping` to something like below (again mind the context added before service url):

```
@RequestMapping("crawler/<rest of the url>")
```